# I tried but failed to print out the id of circles with in the fo loop

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg, jquery-svg

i would like to draw your kind attention (please see below my tries) of the followings where i tried to print out the id's of all circles with in the double for loop but can not. Every time i got null or [object SVGCircleElement].

```
<script>
      const width = document.getElementById("svg239462").viewBox.baseVal.width; //510; //889.37;
      const height = document.getElementById("svg239462").viewBox.baseVal.height; //660; //690.44;

      //console.log(document.getElementById("svg239462"));
      console.log("this is width " + width); //667.030029296875
      console.log("this is height " + height); //517.8300170898438

      var draw = Snap('#svg');

      var c = 0;
      var count = 0;
      let size = Math.round(0.02 * width);

      for (let i = 0; i <= width; i = i + size) {

         count++;

         for (let j = 0; j <= height; j = j + size) {

            var rect = draw.rect(i, j, size, size);
            let circle = draw.circle(i, j, 30); //for circle around the corner of each rectangle

            circle.attr({
               fill: "#b905fa",
               "fill-opacity": 1,
               stroke: "#000",
               "stroke-width": "1px",
               id: "circle_" + (c++), //option3
               name: "circle" + (c++)
            });

            rect.attr({
               fill: "#d00bf3",
               "fill-opacity": 0.1,
               stroke: "#000",
               "stroke-width": "1px",
               id: "rect_" + (c++),
               name: "rect" + (c++)
            });

            //group.add(rect);

            var circleID = document.getElementById($(`#circle_${c++}`));
            //const circleID = document.getElementById($(`#circle_` + c));
            //(`circle_${c++}`); //(`circle_${c}`); //(circle.id);

            console.log("this is ID for circle: " + circleID);

            // Point is outside
            console.log('Point at 10,10:', circleID.isPointInFill(new DOMPoint(50, 50)));

            // Point is inside
            //console.log('Point at 40,30:', circle.isPointInFill(new DOMPoint(40, 30)));

         }
         //console.log("this is ID for circle: " + circleID);

      }

      const circleID = document.getElementById("circle_0"); //(`circle_${c}`);
      console.log("this is ID for circle: " + circleID);

      const selectedElement = document.querySelector('circle_0');
      console.log('.id', selectedElement.id);

      //console.log(selectedElement.toString());

      //console.log('#circle_1');

      console.log("this is for rectangle count: " + count);

      //console.log($('#d_electrolyzer').height());
      //console.log($("#rect908").height());

      if ($("#rect908").height() < $('#d_electrolyzer').height()) {
         console.log("alert");

         $("#rect908").attr({
            fill: "#000",
            "fill-opacity": 1
         });
      } else {
         console.log("alert2");
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById($(`#circle_${c++}`)); doesn't look quite right. Why not use Snap itself, eg output Snap(circle_${c++}).attr('id') maybe

Comment: Thanks for the response....This also worked the following ways around:
const circleID = document.getElementById(`circle_${d}`);
console.log("this is ID for circle: " + circleID.id);